# Which is a faster parser for XML?

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse a simple file, and I want to know between:

- `XML::Simple`
- `XML::Smart`
- `LibXML`

which one is faster?

Comment: Easy: Use XML::LibXML, which has the benefit of using a library written in C. It also implements the familiar DOM. XML::Simple is neither simple, [nor endorsed by its author](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Simple#STATUS-OF-THIS-MODULE). (I'm not qualified to comment on XML::Smart, but judging by the example in the docs, I wouldn't like it very much). If you have very large documents that need to be streamed, use [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig) instead.

Comment: @amon — XML::Simple and XML::Smart both use expat to parse XML, that is written in C too.

Comment: "Streaming" is also possible with `XML::LibXML`, just try `XML::LibXML::Reader` or `XML::LibXML::SAX`.

Comment: Voting to reopen. This is an answer with a specific criteria for evaluating the answer, not a vague "which one's best" question.

Comment: Short answer since I can't post one: I've done extensive benchmarking, and XML::LibXML is the fastest at parsing (and it has a full feature set), but XML::Bare (with a thin layer to assist getting data) is slightly faster when you also factor in the time it takes to extract data from the tree. The difference between these two is tiny compared to the difference between them and most other parsers.

Comment: The speed of XML::Simple varies greatly depending on the parser it uses. XML::Parser is the fastest parser for use with XML::Simple by *far*, yet it's still much much slower than XML::LibXML.

Comment: Voting to reopen, because it NOT off-topic. It is regular question about programming tool and *not opinion* based too. Sure, the OP can write his own benchmark, but thats doesn't mean "off-topic".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

XML::LibXML is the fastest, see the benchmarks at [Ways to Rome](http://xmltwig.org/article/index_wtr.html).

It may or may not matter for a "simple file" (which I assume would mean that it's not too big).

Answer (score 1):

There's also XML::Fast which seems to be a pretty serious contender.  XML::Simple can use XML::LibXML under the hood, but I'm still seeing it as the major CPU drain in my CalDAV testing right now.

It's worth giving it a try if speed is a major consideration for you.